# How to modify a python code to a cython code?

Tags: python, cython, canopy

i have been working on a project on python for physics, using enthought canopy, i wished to enhance it by modifying it to a cython code. Could someone pleases tell me how to rewrite a python to cython codes in canopy? or do i need a separate software?

Answer (score 1):

Just to add, it's probably better to use libraries which already incorporate Cython. [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/) for example, has virtually any array handling you can think of and has been optimized around things like matrix multiplication. Smart people have already done the work for you, so see if you can get that module to do what you need then as a last resort rewrite your code using Cython.

Answer (score 0):

The Canopy Python distribution is bundled with Cython. However to use it, you will need a C compiler on your machine, which you may or may not already have. [The Cython](http://docs.cython.org/src/quickstart/install.html) [documentation](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/cython_tutorial.html#the-basics-of-cython) has a good overview of Cython basics, including a brief description of where to get/find a C compiler for you operating system.